# Multiple websites hosted on same server

Tags: pci-dss

We have two severs sitting under one load balancer. We run PCI scans on those two servers.

Now, when we started, we only had  2 websites running from these two server. But the business is growing and we have around 10 more sites on these two servers.

Do I have to get the PCI scans of all these websites separately, or will it be sufficient to have the PCI scans of server boxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to scan the virtual hosts.

```
3. Prior to scanning the web site and IT infrastructure, merchants and service providers must: 
• Provide the ASV with a list of all Internet-facing IP addresses and/or IP address ranges 
• Provide the ASV with a list of all domains that should be scanned if domain-based virtual hosting is used
```

[Details](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/pdfs/pci_scanning_procedures_v1-1.pdf)

PCI scans are not just testing the security of your operating system, but your web server configuration and application security among other things.